# correct way of doing NOT like

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby on rails 3.0.5 and I have following code

```
scope :foo, where('users.email NOT LIKE "%edu%"')
```

Will the above code work in all three databases: mysql, sqlite3 and postgresql.

Is there a better way to do that using Arel.

Answer (score 3):

```
where(:conditions => ["not(users.email LIKE %?%)",'edu'])
```